Confusion in conservation of momentum
Two masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ are attached to the two ends of a rope that is sent through a pulley. Then a mass $M$ is dropped onto the mass $m_1$ from a $h$ height. So when the law of conservation of momentum is applied to the system, should I use
$$Mv_1=(M+m_1)v_2 + m_2v_2$$taking the velocity of $m_2$ as (+) or, $$Mv_1=(M+m_1)v_2 + (-m_2v_2)$$taking the velocity of the of $m_2$ as (-)? In a book I am reading the solution to a similar problem only comes correctly if I take the velocity of $m_2$ as (+). The thing I am confused is why can't I take the velocity of $m_2$ as (-) since we know the direction mass $m_2$ is going to move is the opposite of $m_1$.


Before you start using any formulas, decide on what coordinate system you want to use: where is the origin, and what direction(s) do the axis/axes point in. Then all signs follow from that: is it along the positive axis direction it is +, otherwise it's -.

Drawing a diagram often helps.

Admittedly the context of the question is a homework-like exercise, but a specific concept – conservation of momentum – is being asked about.

Remember that the vector sum of bodies' momenta is conserved provided that no forces act on the bodies except forces between the bodies themselves.
If the masses are the bodies in your system (and the mass of the rope is negligible) we do have an external force, that is a force not between the masses themselves. It is the force that the pulley exerts on the rope joining the masses. This (upward) force will increase pulse-like when $M$ falls on $m_1$. [And the rope will exert pulse-like forces on $m_1$ and $m_2$]. This is why momentum, calculated as a vector sum of the masses' momenta, is not conserved.
A full analysis would take this force into account. At high school level it is usual to wave ones hands and to claim that the two masses joined by a rope are 'equivalent' to a single mass, $(m_1+m_2)$! You may think this unsatisfactory.
[Incidentally, we seem to be assuming that $m_1$ and $m_2$ are at rest when $M$ is dropped on $m_1$; that is they haven't had time to accelerate because of the different gravitational forces on them.]
